# Redirect VxWorks Workbench Terminal output to a file

Tags: serial-port, vxworks, workbench

I am using Workbench 3.1 and the Terminal feature to capture printf output directly over a serial port. I'd like to capture that data from within Workbench to a file, but am unable to find any options within the GUI to enable that.

There are options to log backend and WTX data to files, but nothing that seems to capture the serial output. I have access to putty (no hyperterminal though), but I would prefer to keep the setup the same (terminal within Workbench).

Is there some option for that I may have missed? If not, anyone got a workaround that can be done from within the workbench environment? Capturing COM1 serial data (our port) directly outside of workbench would be my last resort.

The host shell is not used directly for this work (strictly loading targets through the gui and using the terminal window for interaction).

Comment: Thanks for fixing that awful formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

In Workbench 3.1, when creating a new remote session, there is a general pop-up with target options and other tabs of options. One of those tabs has the Virtual Environment and an area to select where to place the log files. If enabled, this log file will capture all data seen on the workspace terminal window automatically.